# How can I use Jsoup to turn unallowed html tag delimiter into entities where there are unallowed tags

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Using Jsoup clean is it possible to convert this string:

```
Here is some <b>important</b> stuff that can't have 
<script>javascript</script> or the following embed tag 
<embed src="helloworld.swf" type="application/vnd.adobe.flash-movie"> movie 
in the output
```

to this :

```
Here is some <b>important</b> stuff that can't have 
&lt;script&gt;javascript&lt;/script&gt; or the following embed tag 
&lt;embed src="helloworld.swf" type="application/vnd.adobe.flash-movie"&gt;
movie in the output
```

so it renders

> Here is some **important** stuff that can't have 
>       <script>javascript</script> or the following embed tag 
>       <embed src="helloworld.swf" type="application/vnd.adobe.flash-movie">
>       movie in the output

Where the bold tag is allowed and left alone but the script and embed tags delimiters change from `< >` to `&lt; and &gt;` so they are treated as just text and not real html elements.

What settings are necessary to accomplish this? I have:

```
    private static String limitHtml(String value) {
    String result = value;
    if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
        Document.OutputSettings settings = new Document.OutputSettings();
        settings.prettyPrint(false);

        // what other settings ???

        Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none().addTags(ALLOWED_HTML_TAGS);
        whitelist.addAttributes(":all", ALLOWED_HTML_ATTRIBUTES);
        result = Jsoup.clean(value, "", whitelist, settings);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there a similar Java lib that can accomplish this if Jsoup doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup can definitively get your back here. The trick is to use a dummy document (`transitional` variable in the code) with a single `pre` element in it.

We will simply add each unallowed element found in this `pre` element.
Later, we replace the unallowed element in the initial value with its escaped html code.

#### CODE

```
// Comma separated list of allowed tags.
private static String ALLOWED_HTML_TAGS_CSS_QUERY = "b,span";

private static String limitHtml(String value) {
    String result = value;
    if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
        // Build a sided document. It will help us escape unallowed tags. 
        Document transitional = Jsoup.parse("<pre></pre>");
        
        // Parse the actual value for finding unallowed tags
        Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(value, "");
        Elements unallowedElements = doc.select("*:not("+ALLOWED_HTML_TAGS_CSS_QUERY+")");

        for (Element e : unallowedElements) {
            switch (e.tagName()) {
            case "#root": case "html": case "head": case "body":
                // Those tags are added automatically by Jsoup. Nothing to do...
                break;

            default:
                // Load the unallowed element to escape its html code in the transitional document
                Element pre = transitional.select("pre").first().text(e.outerHtml());
                
                // Replace unallowed element with its escape html code
                e.replaceWith(new TextNode(pre.text(), ""));
            }
        }

        // Get the final sanitized value
        Document.OutputSettings settings = new Document.OutputSettings();
        settings.prettyPrint(false);

        Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none().addTags(ALLOWED_HTML_TAGS);
        whitelist.addAttributes(":all", ALLOWED_HTML_ATTRIBUTES);
        result = Jsoup.clean(doc.body().html(), "", whitelist, settings);
    }

    return result;
}
```

#### SAMPLE USAGE

```
String unsanitizedHtml = "Here is some <b>important</b> stuff that can't have " + //
        "<script>javascript</script> or the following embed tag " + //
        "<embed src=\"helloworld.swf\" type=\"application/vnd.adobe.flash-movie\"> movie" + //
        "in the output";

System.out.println("BEFORE:\n" + unsanitizedHtml);
System.out.println();
System.out.println("AFTER:\n" + limitHtml(unsanitizedHtml));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
BEFORE:
Here is some <b>important</b> stuff that can't have <script>javascript</script> or the following embed tag <embed src="helloworld.swf" type="application/vnd.adobe.flash-movie"> moviein the output

AFTER:
Here is some <b>important</b> stuff that can't have &lt;script&gt;javascript&lt;/script&gt; or the following embed tag &lt;embed src="helloworld.swf" type="application/vnd.adobe.flash-movie"&gt; moviein the output
```